# Spurious note in "Für Elise" (D in measure 76)?

Tags: beethoven, editions

Back in the olden days, when I walked to school barefoot in the snow uphill both ways, I learned "Für Elise" out of *Suzuki Piano School Volume 5*. In m. 76 (third measure in the below image), there is a lovely E7 chord.

[image: "Für Elise" mm. 74-77, Suzuki version]

Imagine my horror and dismay when today I heard the piece performed *without the D*, simply an E major chord. Yet, a brief [perusal of IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/F%C3%BCr_Elise%2C_WoO_59_(Beethoven%2C_Ludwig_van)) confirmed that, indeed, the chord is a humble E major, not a lovely E7. For example, here is the first edition (other editions agree):

[image: "Für Elise" first edition excerpt]

**What is the origin of the E7 chord in the Suzuki edition?** Will Beethoven forgive me? Does the world still have meaning? Is there a Santa Claus?

Note: The St. Petersburg edition on IMSLP also contains the note in question.

Comment: Maybe you should ask Santa to give you that E7 :p ?

Comment: @Tom Touché. Well done.

Comment: …and you tell that to the kids of today, they don't believe a word of it [A. N. Other Yorkshireman]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it looks as if someone 'improved' it along the way!

Arguments for a plain E chord - It's perfectly sufficient and 'correct'.  It maintains the 4-note texture rather than slipping into 5-note for just one chord.  It seems to be what Beethoven wrote.

Arguments for E7 - Someone thought it sounded better.

Do we have a winner?   Perhaps.  But even first editions may be questioned.   The same note in the same harmony (but in a different  part of the work) is also questioned.
Welcome to the fascinating world of musical authenticity!

https://www.henle.de/blog/en/2011/11/30/beethoven-fur-elise-woo-59-%E2%80%93-do-you-strike-the-right-note/

Comment: Regarding your remark:  "Arguments for E7 - Someone thought it sounded better." Well, others could make the argument that E sounds better. Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I think maintaining the 4-note texture sounds better.  But I don't get to decide!

Comment: I certainly also prefer to play a clean E major chord. A clean E major combined with the dynamics and note values sounds really great to me. The music becomes very soft at this point, with a soft E major chord which it is only an eight note. The softness and atmosphere is disturbed if you add a D. Thus just an E chord.

Answer (score -1):

4-part harmony doesn't like to have 5 notes "just 'cuz".

That being said, the modern ear and sensibilities are so far past classical theory that if I were you, I would totally go ahead and add the 7th "just 'cuz."

What's the point of playing a timeless classic if you can't make Beethoven roll over in his grave? :D

Comment: The question is on the origin of the note, which appears in multiple editions, rather than on whether or not to play it. Perhaps you could add some information on when or by which editor it was added?